# missing '=' etcd when defining service file

Tags: kubernetes, rhel7, etcd

I'm struggling while following Kelsey Hightower's "Kubernetes the Hard Way" tutorial. I've gone off script, because I'm trying to bootstrap k8s on a local server.

I've got the point where I'm bootstrapping etcd, however, when I'm creating the service I'm getting an error:

```
Failed to start etcd.service: Unit is not loaded properly: Bad message.
See system logs and 'systemctl status etcd.service' for details.
```

Checking the logs and I get:

```
Jun 21 20:16:49 controller-0 systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/etcd.service:9] Missing '='.
Jun 21 20:16:49 controller-0 systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/etcd.service:9] Missing '='.
Jun 21 20:17:25 controller-0 systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/etcd.service:9] Missing '='.
```

Here's the etcd.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=etcd service
Documentation=https://github.com/coreos/etcd

[Service]
User=etcd
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/etcd \\
 --name ${ETCD_NAME} \\
 --data-dir /var/lib/etcd \\
 --initial-advertise-peer-urls http://${ETCD_HOST_IP}:2380 \\
 --listen-peer-urls http://${ETCD_HOST_IP}:2380 \\
 --listen-client-urls http://${ETCD_HOST_IP}:2379,http://127.0.0.1:2379 \\
 --advertise-client-urls http://${ETCD_HOST_IP}:2379 \\
 --initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster-1 \\
 --initial-cluster etcd-1=http://192.168.0.7:2380 \\
 --initial-cluster-state new \\
 --heartbeat-interval 1000 \\
 --election-timeout 5000
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Are you sure that is your unit file? Some lines appear to be missing, and there appear to be extra characters at the end of some lines.

Comment: you're right, I missed the first line which is [Unit]. I added it. The \\ are because the one line is extremely long

Comment: You should have one backslash, not two.

Comment: Hello @Baron, Could you add your solution as an answer and mark it as approved? It will make your solution more visible if anyone will be searching for similar issues.

Answer (score 3):

The answer was pointed out by @Michael Hampton. The two backslashes were because the code was supposed to be written from the terminal (in the guide). In the etcd.service file, lines should be broken with a single .

```
[Unit]
Description=etcd service
Documentation=https://github.com/coreos/etcd

[Service]
User=etcd
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/etcd \
 --name ${ETCD_NAME} \
 --data-dir /var/lib/etcd \
 --initial-advertise-peer-urls http://${ETCD_HOST_IP}:2380 \
 --listen-peer-urls http://${ETCD_HOST_IP}:2380 \
 --listen-client-urls http://${ETCD_HOST_IP}:2379,http://127.0.0.1:2379 \
 --advertise-client-urls http://${ETCD_HOST_IP}:2379 \
 --initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster-1 \
 --initial-cluster etcd-1=http://192.168.0.7:2380 \
 --initial-cluster-state new \
 --heartbeat-interval 1000 \
 --election-timeout 5000
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```